# p:ajax inside ui:include doesnt update content (Facelets + PrimeFaces)

Tags: ajax, jsf, include, primefaces

I'm having a problem with PrimeFaces AJAX and the UI:Include. I'm trying to do a AJAX-based web form, by using the tag ui:include: When I click on menu button, it changes the SRC on include and load the next page. Everything is working fine, but when I try to use some AJAX on page that has been loaded by ui:include, it doesnt update. Well, I think the code will show what i'm saying:

Main page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<f:view contentType="text/html">
    <h:head>
        <f:facet name="first">
            <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
            <title>PrimeFaces</title>
        </f:facet>
        <ui:include src="#{layout.head}"></ui:include>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
        <p:layout fullPage="true" >
            [...]
            <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                <p:panel styleClass="noBorder" id="#{pageFlow.panelId}">
                    <ui:insert name="mainContent">
                        <ui:include src="#{pageFlow.page}"/>
                    </ui:insert>
                </p:panel>
            </p:layoutUnit>
        </p:layout>
        <p:growl id="globalMessages" showDetail="true" severity="warn, error, fatal" autoUpdate="true"></p:growl>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

template.xhtml - The page to be loadad in include:

```
<ui:fragment
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <p:messages  id="resultMessage" showDetail="true" severity="info" autoUpdate="true" closable="true"/>
    <p:panel  styleClass="noBorder">
        <p:panel id="templateBody" header="Cadastro de Template" style="margin: 10px">
            <h:panelGrid cellpadding="3">
                <p:row>
                    <p:column><h:outputLabel value="Nome: "/></p:column>
                    <p:column><p:inputText value="#{template.name}"/></p:column>
                    <p:column><h:outputLabel value="Descrição: "/></p:column>
                    <p:column><p:inputText value="#{template.description}"/></p:column>
                </p:row>
                <p:row><p:column><p:separator/></p:column></p:row>
                <p:row>
                    <p:column><h:outputLabel style="vertical-align: middle" value="Provedor: "/></p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:selectOneMenu style="vertical-align: middle" validator="selectOneMenuValidator" converter="selectOneMenuConverter" id="providers" value="#{template.providerName}">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{template.testItems}"/>
                            <f:attribute name="fieldName" value="template.providerName"/>
                            <p:ajax update="selectAvaliableItems"/>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
                <p:row>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:panel id="selectItem" styleClass="noBorder" style="alignment-adjust: central; float: left; height: 200px; width: 100%">
                            <p:selectManyMenu converter="selectManyMenuConverter" validator="selectManyMenuValidator" value="#{template.selectedAvaliableItems}" style="float: left; height: 180px; width: 300px" id="selectAvaliableItems">
                                <f:selectItems value="#{template.avaliableItems}"/>
                                <f:attribute name="fieldName" value="template.selectedAvaliableItems"/>
                            </p:selectManyMenu>
                            <p:panel styleClass="noBorder" style="float: left; height: 180px; width: 75px">
                                <p:commandButton value="&gt;&gt;" update="selectItem" actionListener="#{template.setAction(8+0)}"/>
                                <p:commandButton value="&gt;" update="selectItem" actionListener="#{template.setAction(8+1)}"/>
                                <p:commandButton value="&lt;" update="selectItem" actionListener="#{template.setAction(16+1)}"/>
                                <p:commandButton value="&lt;&lt;" update="selectItem" actionListener="#{template.setAction(16+0)}"/>
                            </p:panel>
                            <p:selectManyMenu converter="selectManyMenuConverter" validator="selectManyMenuValidator" value="#{template.selectedChosenItems}" style="float: left;height: 180px; width: 300px" id="selectSelectedItems">
                                <f:selectItems value="#{template.chosenItems}"/>
                                <f:attribute name="fieldName" value="template.selectedChosenItems"/>
                            </p:selectManyMenu>
                        </p:panel>
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
                <p:row>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:commandButton id="saveBtn" value="Salvar" update="templateBody" action="#{template.sendData}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" update="@all" action="home"/>
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>
    </p:panel>
    <p:blockUI block="templateBody" trigger="saveBtn providers">
            <p:graphicImage value="./files/img/todo/loading.gif" />
    </p:blockUI>
</ui:fragment>
```

The flowPage bean do its job fine, it return a String with the file name to be loaded base on the MenuButton clicked. The problem is that every AJAX on the template.xhtml doesnt update its content. The blockUI is called and I got a requisition, but no content update...

Any idea?

If I remove the ui:include and use the template strategy, it works fine, but I want a AJAX navigation page.

Thx for your attention.

Comment: I found the problem. When I do a new request, my pageFlowBean is new instancied and the getPage is null returned.

Thx for your attention.

Comment: Add your answer and accept it please, for future viewers.